# Api запрос миниатюры с Youtube по названию (не путать с id) Java, Android

Tags: java, android-studio, api, youtube, thumbnails

Собственно вопрос. Направьте в нужном направлении. Как выглядит запрос миниатюры (thumbnail) с Youtube по имени или названию произведения? Буду благодарен за фрагмент кода. Ключ для запроса есть - я его получил. А вот на developers.google.com был - не разобрался, сорри.

Comment: С одним и тем же названием может быть несколько видео же.

Comment: Если вы внимательно прочитали мой вопрос, то я интересовался в части программного кода для Android на Java. Если будет несколько миниатюр, то я найду как обработать.

Comment: сначала делаете поиск по строке, и по найденным id уже извлекаете миниатюры. Просто поставляете id в ссылку i.ytimg.com/vi/<тут ID>/hqdefault.jpg и это будет ссылка на превью.